# How can I install Epson A3 printer and scanner drivers?

Tags: printing, samsung, scanner, epson

I have 2 printers- SAMSUNG ML1676 and EPSON stylus 1390 (A3 printer) and 1 scanner EPSON GT1500.
I have installed samsung printer, but unable to install either of the epson product.
The drivers does not install and show me dependency fails always.

Please, someone help me installing of locate the correct drivers.
Ubuntu version i am using is 12.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are installing a `.deb` file.

If you are getting dependency issues, it means that the driver your installing requires packages that are not yet installed on your machine.

So open a terminal and run:

```
sudo dpkg -i <the location of the .deb package>
```

This should say that there was a problem with dependencies, so now it had informed your system about them. Next run:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Which will download and install missing dependencies on your system that it finds. So after running the command, if all the required dependencies were found, just run the first command a second time.

```
sudo dpkg -i <the location of the .deb package>
```

This time it should run without any error if all the dependencies were already installed.

If this still didn't work, please edit your question and add the output of the each of the commands so we can help you further.